# Angular - Directive change value of form control value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using custom directive to change format of number but when I access to value by this.form.controls['montant'].value I find the number converted, but I wish to have it not formatted.
Example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzaxip

Answer (score 1):

That's how custom directives work. Once your directive has changed the value in the element itself, you have lost your original value.

As a workaround, what you can do is, whatever operation your directive is performing undo it while saving the value.

Better option would be display the formatted value in a label next to the input element and save the original value as it is.